# ActionProvider. Change text in submenu and know when its pressed

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I use this example
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider
But, i want to now, if its possible change the text "see all" for other text, for example, my gallery app, have the text in spanish "ver todo", if possible to change?

And.. if possible know when the share button in the action bar (in my case actionbarsherlock) are press?

i see "However, if the action provider provides a submenu of actions, then your activity does not receive a call to onOptionsItemSelected() when the user opens the list or selects one of the submenu items" but..no other way to know it? I want that when the user press that "button" make one accion also show the list of app to share.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
 {      
        MenuInflater inflater= getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_resultados, menu);



        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_compartir); 

        mShareActionProvider =(com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

        return true;
    }


private Intent createShareIntent ()
{
       Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"TestText");
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TestSubject");


       return shareIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the string at actionbarsherlock 's project, by changing lines at `res/values/abs__strings`, or you could create a folder `res/values-es`, copy there `abs__strings`, and edit the lines there. That way, you would have both english and spanish strings on your code, depending on device's language. The line you're looking for in `abs__strings` is called `abs__activity_chooser_view_see_all`.

Just a tip, try using the search function in Eclipse for these string changing next time. I found this out by searching "See all...".

About knowing when the button has been pressed, I couldn't figure it out. I just tested that `onOptionsItemSelected()` does not work, just as you said...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  `setOnMenuItemClickListener`  for ex:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_compartir);
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```